# Add sails route path to default URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, routes, sails.js

I have a `node` server that uses **Sails framework**.

When I run, it returns this message:

```
info: To see your app, visit http://localhost:1337
info: To shut down Sails, press <CTRL> + C at any time.
```

**Is possible to add a route path to the default URL?**

Instead of `http://localhost:1337`, use `http://localhost:1337/test/`

I tried to run with `npm start sails lift --appPath=/test/` but does not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Sails.js to lift to a specific page during testing you can make a new view-action (or use `view-homepage-or-redirect` if you downloaded the app)
 then in the action you can set

```
if (sails.config.environment !== 'production') {
   throw {redirect:'/test'};
}
```

If you end up making a new action for this dont forget to add it to your `routes.js`

Comment: Into `module.exports.routes` @Raqem?

Comment: Your `config.routes.js` like:  `GET /':   { action: 'view-homepage-or-redirect' }`